# Is it possible to destructure a map in a bind?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

Is it possible to do this in one function:

```
(binding [*configs* (merge default-configs configs)]
    (let [{:keys [login url max-pages]} *configs*]
      ..
```

When I tried this:

```
(binding [{:keys [login url max-pages] :as *configs*} (merge default-configs configs)]
```

It gave me this error:

> CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol

A little googling showed me that Common Lisp has a function called `destructure-bind` but I'm not sure if that's related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nothing like this will work with core macros.

The reason is that both `binding` and `let` (and friends, e.g. `with-bindings`) do just one thing. In the case of `binding`, that thing is installing thread-local bindings for Vars; for `let`, it is introducing local bindings. These are entirely different operations.

In `let`, destructuring has a clear meaning: it introduces new locals, which is exactly what the basic, non-destructuring `let` bindings do. This is also clearly useful, as prying appart data structures and binding different parts to different locals is a common need. The names of the locals are also locally determined, so things like `:keys` in associative destructuring work well.

In `binding`, to be consistent with its main purpose, destructuring would need to bind several Vars simultaneously to several parts of a data structure. This is not nearly as useful. If instead destructuring in `binding` were to introduce locals, then all of a sudden `binding` would do two unrelated things, possibly both in the same binding pair (note how the failing `binding` form from the question text expects the bindings introduced by `:keys` to be locals, but the binding made by `:as` to be the usual thread-local binding of a Var). Thus `binding` simply opts not to support destructuring. (If you need to bind parts of a data structure to several Vars, you can use a `let` to perform the destructuring, then install the bindings with `binding`.)

---

As for `destructuring-bind`, it's basically the destructuring-enabled version of `let` in Common Lisp. CL's `let` does not support destructuring.

Comment: That makes sense, I never thought about, "will these `:keys` be local or dynamic scoped?"

Answer (score 1):

"Binding Forms (Destructuring)" [section](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29):

> Clojure supports abstract structural binding, often called
>   destructuring, in let binding lists, fn parameter lists, and any macro
>   that expands into a let or fn. ...

AFAIK `binding` itself doesn't use destructuring mechanism (via `fn` of `let`).